# looping method for a constructor

Tags: java, loops

How should i loop this constructor? Arguments are passed from a text file. I've tried a while-loop, but it does not even read the first line of my text file. My text file contains the ff:
`s0,a,s0,a,-1 (--next line--) s0,b,s0,b,-1`. If I don't use a loop, it gets the contents of my text file, and passes it to the constructor.
EDIT: i've corrected and marked the constructor to be looped. If I include the second while-loop, it does not get the contents of the text file.

Edit2: the first while loop puts the contents of my text file to an array named argument. The 2nd while-loop does the looping for passing the contents of the argument array to the variables, which then passes it to the constructor. This 2nd while-loop doesn't work.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("D:\\Kirk\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TuringMachine\\src\\turingmachine\\Algorithms.txt"));
String data = scanner.nextLine();
String[] arguments = data.split(",");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data);
int i = 0;
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) { //loop for putting contents of text file to array
    arguments[i++] = st.nextToken();
}//end loop


while(scanner.hasNextLine()){  //loop transition function(not working)
    String fromstate = arguments[0];
    String read = arguments[1];
    String tostate = arguments[2];
    String write = arguments[3];
    int move = Integer.parseInt(arguments[4]);
    trans.add(new Transition(new StateTapeSymbolPair(fromstate, read), new StateTapeSymbolPair(tostate, write),move));
    //loop the above constructor
}//end while
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Which constructor? What does 'loop a constructor' mean? Edit your question and add some more details, perhaps add some comments to your code pointing out the bits your question is about.

Comment: okay, I've edited the code. I've commented on which while-loop i'm having trouble with, abd the code i need to loop

Comment: It's still unclear what you are asking. Are you saying the inner while doesn't loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not looping to get data of eah line.
Here an example :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Algorithms.txt"));

    while(scanner.hasNext()){

         String data = scanner.nextLine();     // your line          
         String[] arguments = data.split(","); // split the line

         // getting data for each data inside the line
              String fromstate = arguments[0];
                String read = arguments[1];
                String tostate = arguments[2];
                String write = arguments[3];
                int move = Integer.parseInt(arguments[4]);

               System.out.println(fromstate+"-"+read+"-"+tostate+"-"+write+"-"+move);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks! So my error is that I put my String data and arguments array inside a separate array?

Comment: there are some errrors in the code. you get the first line of the file and you put each data of this line in an array according to "," separator, then you update the first element of this array wih the first line value. and finally you loop wih a true condition to get the data of this array. you don't point to the line you want to split.